# Magento hosting requirements for 1.9?

Tags: magento-1, magento-enterprise, hosting

What are hosting requirements for magento 1.9 ? My website have 1000 visits per day and have narrow my choice to 2 providers:

1.https://www.tmdhosting.com/magento-hosting.html

2.https://www.nexcess.net/magento/hosting

Answer (score 5):

At 1000 uniques per day, you should be looking at entry level dedicated.

- 4 Threads/8GB RAM will be good for up to 2k uniques/day on a properly configured machine.
- 8 Threads/16GB RAM will be good for up to 4k uniques per day.

What you need to account for is your catalogue size and disk utilisation, as this will impact how much RAM and what capacity disks you'll need.

- 8GB RAM for <1k SKUs
- 16GB RAM for <50k SKUs
- 32GB RAM for <100k SKUs

You don't need SSDs, its a "nice to have" but by no means will have any real world performance impact at your scale.

---

Now of course, you'll get responses here from those running their store on the equivalent of a Raspberry Pi - my advice would be to ignore it. Invest in the right infrastructure and you can totally forgot about hosting and just grow the business.

Done right, you'll set up hosting and not speak to your provider until time for renewal/expansion.

Invest in hosting, it isn't a cost of business, it's an extremely important core component.

Sources:

- https://www.sonassihosting.com/help/magestack/cpu-sizing/
- https://www.sonassihosting.com/help/magestack/ram-sizing/

Answer (score 1):

The hosting requirements for Magento 1.9 include a web server (Apache or Nginx), PHP 5.4 to 5.6, and MySQL 5.6 or later. For optimal performance, consider caching mechanisms, a CDN, and optimized database configuration.

Regarding the hosting providers you mentioned:

TMD Hosting (https://www.tmdhosting.com/magento-hosting.html): They offer Magento-optimized hosting plans. Ensure the plan meets Magento's requirements and consider server performance, uptime guarantees, support, and pricing.

Nexcess (https://www.nexcess.net/magento/hosting): Known for managed Magento hosting, verify that their plans align with Magento 1.9 requirements. Evaluate server infrastructure, customer reviews, support quality, and pricing.

Consider factors such as reputation, customer support, reliability, scalability, server location, backup options, and security when making your choice.