# What are the hardware requirements for running Magento 2.0?

Tags: magento2, performance, server-setup

I have tried installing Magento on a shared hosting solution but it is unbearably slow. I have decided to host my future online store on a VPS. What would Magento experts say are the hardware requirements in order to have an above average performance?
I plan on going through the installation process with diligence, tending to cache configuration and other possible ways to optimize for performance.

**This is the VPS I chose:**

```
-4 vCores (KVM virtualization)  
-14GB RAM  
-1000GB Disk space  
-100Mbps connection
```

**I can upgrade to the following setup with a pricing delta of ~222$ per year.**

```
-6 vCores  
-30GB RAM  
-2000GB Disk space  
-1Gbps connection
```

I think I should be OK in terms of processing cores (am I?), but I'd like an opinion about the connection bandwidth and RAM.

EDIT: I have checked [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/84787/magento-hosting-requirements-for-1-9), and although the question is similar, I'm looking for an above average performance, and not just minimum requirements to host a Magento shop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want to boost your magento2 performance it's mainly about caching.

First, be sure you are in production mode for performance tests
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/bootstrap/magento-modes.html

Next step would be to use a cahe storage server instead of file caching. For xample a redis server
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/redis/config-redis.html

Last but not least, varnish can give you an awesome performance boost
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish.html

If you also want the uncached sites to load faster I would recommend to ask your Hoster for SSD Storage.

14 GB RAM should be enough. Be sure, that you adjust your mysql configuration so the ram is used and not only burning your money ;P

CPU Core count should only be a thing if you have enough requests that your average server load goes up and responses cannot be processed in a reasonable time anymore. But, with activated varnish, its not so easy to get there.

Comment: I have never heard about about Varnish. Is it something like CloudFlare? Thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: very basically spoken it's a full page cache server that's in front of your webserver that, corretly configured, serves all static content from cache and can request dynamic site parts from the webserver. At the beginning its pretty complicated, but the integration in magento2 works pretty well so far and magento creates a whole configuration file for you.

Comment: But does that involve acquiring a new server just to serve as a cache server or can I use the same VPS to run Varnish?

Comment: you can use the same server. You (or your hoster) have to configure varnish listening on port 80 and then configure the webserver on another port (8080 is pretty popular for that ;P). Then you have to insert the configuration values in magento backend and create the varnish config. Then load it into your varnish server (on debian the default config loaded on varnish startup lies under /etc/varnish/default.vcl)

Comment: The documentation page that you linked in the original answer.. Does it guide developers throughout the configuration process you are describing now??

Comment: it covers most of it. there is still one problem - that varnish does not support ssl. It's mentioned in the docu but only linked to a wikipedia site explaining what a TLS termination proxy is, but not how to configure one. Maybe your hoster can help you out with this. (with a bit deeper knowledge of webservers its not really a big thing)